# Unexplained variables in linear model output

Tags: r, lm

Could anyone please shed a light on why instead of displaying Month^1, Month^2 and Month^3, my model summary showed Month.L, Month.Q, Month.C. Also, what month did the Intercept refer to: January or December (please find attached image)?
[image: Unexplained/inconsistent variable names]

Comment: The issue is your predictor is an ordered factor.  The appended letters are for the polynomial functions being fitted (linear, quadratic, cubic and so on).

Comment: You should check that polynomial contrasts are what you actually want - fitting a polynomial of degree 11 allows for a very complex pattern of change that's hard to interpret.

Comment: I'd recommend *not* using an ordered factor if you want normal contrasts with a reference level. See a little example [in this R help thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-January/123268.html), including this quote from Peter Dalgaard, *"Some, including me, feel that  having polynomials as default
contrasts for ordered factors is a bit of a design misfeature - It was
inherited from S, but assigning equidistant numerical values to ordered
groups isn't really well-founded, and does become plainly wrong when the
levels are really something like 0, 3, 6, 12, 18, 24 months.*"

Comment: To un-order it do `training$Month = factor(training$Month, ordered = FALSE)`. Also note that *ordered* is somewhat a misnomer - the levels still have the correct order, but you will get the default treatment contrasts where each month is compared to the reference month (first level). See `?contrasts` for a bit of detail.

Comment: Thank you all for your enlightenment. Much appreciated. So by using ordered factor, R mistakenly modeled it as polynomial of degree 11, that is lm(PaxOut ~ Month^11, training) instead of linear regression as I specified in lm(PaxOut ~ Month, training)? By the way, the reason I ordered the Month was to graph the PaxOut against the Month. Honestly, without your help, I would never ever figure this out.